# What formations are to be expected to develop between the transform boundaries of oceanic and continental plates?

Tags: plate-tectonics

This could be needed in the Worldbuilding stack exchange instead of here, but when I was mapping out the movements of the tectonic plates, then there's a few locations where oceanic and continental plates are moving parallel to one another in opposite directions, creating transform boundaries.

I can't find anything regarding the formations that would arise from this, though I expect that something along the lines of cliffs might form, though this is pure speculation. What formations should I expect?

And as a side-note, I also found many cases of when one plate is moving parallel to the boundary, but the other plate is moving either convergent or divergent of that boundary. What formations should I expect from these as well?

Answer (score 1):

The [San Andreas Fault system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Andreas_Fault) is an excellent example of what can happen in an oceanic–continental transform fault.

It's also important to remember that plate boundaries are usually never 100% transform-like and are at an angle. This would cause either compression or extension, depending on the local geometry. A [pull apart basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-apart_basin) is an example of something like this. For instance, the dead sea is a basin on a transform fault between Israel and Jordan, and a few hundreds kilometres to the north, on the same transform, you have mountains between Lebanon and Syria.